# Combine differently sized graphics with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am processing a large batch of images that have a silver coloured coin on a black background.  First I trim the files using by calculating the dimensions from:
    trimbox=$(convert $f -fuzz 35% -format "%@" info:)

I add 50 to the first 2 parameters and 25 to each of the last 2 (to cause more of the original picture to be visible beyond what trim detects).  I have tested by removing these offsets with no difference.

```
convert "$f" -crop "$trimbox" +repage "$baseFilename-trimmed.jpg"
```

Once trimmed I am using:

```
    command="$baseoFilename-trimmed.jpg $baserFilename-trimmed.jpg "
    command2="+repage _MG_$first"
    convert $command -append $command2-vmerged.jpg
    convert $command +append $command2-hmerged.jpg
```

to merge the files.  I have tried variants with -background black or -fill black to no avail.

The thin white rectangle is appearing because the two images are slightly differently sized.

I would prefer them to be resized identically so that no correction would be needed but would also accept a black bar.

Samples of files:

- [Original file 1](http://realmsofdespair.info/img/_MG_7348.jpg)
- [Original file 2](http://realmsofdespair.info/img/_MG_7349.jpg)
- [Trimmed file 1](http://realmsofdespair.info/img/_MG_7348-trimmed.jpg)
- [Trimmed file 2](http://realmsofdespair.info/img/_MG_7349-trimmed.jpg)
- [Merged file 1](http://realmsofdespair.info/img/_MG_7349-hmerged.jpg)
- [Merged file 2](http://realmsofdespair.info/img/_MG_7349-vmerged.jpg)

Viewing these on a white background of course obscures what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Homey_D_Clown_IT Added some information.  The command lines are very basic.

Answer (score 1):

This script should do what you want. It uses the maximum width or the maximum height of the images when trimming.

```bash
# !/bin/bash

set -eu

gettrimbox() {
    # Some lines were based on the code of Fred Weinhaus available on http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/autotrim/
    trimbox=$(convert "$1" -fuzz 35% -format "%@" info: | tr -cs "0-9\n" " ")
    r_w=$(echo $trimbox | cut -d\  -f1)
    r_h=$(echo $trimbox | cut -d\  -f2)
    r_xoff=$(echo $trimbox | cut -d\  -f3)
    r_yoff=$(echo $trimbox | cut -d\  -f4)
    r_xcenter=$(((r_w/2)+r_xoff))
    r_ycenter=$(((r_h/2)+r_yoff))
    r_w=$((r_w+50))
    r_h=$((r_h+50))
}

f1=$1
f2=$2
number1=$(echo "$f1" | tr -dc "0-9")

gettrimbox "$f1"
w1=$r_w; h1=$r_h
xcenter1=$r_xcenter; ycenter1=$r_ycenter

gettrimbox "$f2"
w2=$r_w; h2=$r_h
xcenter2=$r_xcenter; ycenter2=$r_ycenter

if [ $w1 -gt $w2 ]; then max_w=$w1; else max_w=$w2; fi
if [ $h1 -gt $h2 ]; then max_h=$h1; else max_h=$h2; fi

convert "$f1"[$max_w"x"$h1+$((xcenter1-(max_w/2)))+$((ycenter1-(h1/2)))] \
        "$f2"[$max_w"x"$h2+$((xcenter2-(max_w/2)))+$((ycenter2-(h2/2)))] \
        -append +repage "_MG_$number1-vmerged.jpg"

convert "$f1"[$w1"x"$max_h+$((xcenter1-(w1/2)))+$((ycenter1-(max_h/2)))] \
        "$f2"[$w2"x"$max_h+$((xcenter2-(w2/2)))+$((ycenter2-(max_h/2)))] \
        +append +repage "_MG_$number1-hmerged.jpg"
```

Comment: Unfortunately although this solution does eliminate the white bar it is causing a lot of variance in the mutual center of the images resulting in a very unappealing final presentation.    It is also sometimes causing crops that remove detail from the image.  I'll look at the formulae and see if I can make a correction that works.

Comment: @Stephen If possible, provide some images that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use Irfanview64 rather than Imagemagick

- It has flexible imaging tools
- launch Thumbnails with "T" to launch the Thumbnails App
- you can browse folder and even load from>Edit add all subfolders<
- options for thumbnails are extensive
- you can select many images with Ctrl + click key
- then >file>create contact sheet) and adjust array size x*y and space between etc etc

[image]
[image]

Comment: Though I appreciate your answer however I am using ImageMagick on a large batch of images (over 1200 and growing) and for a number of other steps ... conversion, temperature adjustment, auto-crop, merge, label, etc in a largely scripted manner.  I'm not particularly inclined to abandon it over a 3 pixel white line.

Comment: understood   now that you mention this   .